# How to force cloud functions not to persist variables between invocations?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

*Originally titled: How to force cloud functions to always use the latest version?*

**ORIGINAL QUESTION** (since others may encounter this issue)

I've got a cloud function that I update with some regularity. I've noticed (through console logging the a hard-coded number I change with each update) that after updates, a large percentage of invocations still use the old version for hours or even *days* afterwards. It's not uncommon for 50%+ of my invocations to end up using an old version.

I'm updating like this:

```
gcloud functions deploy functionName --runtime nodejs12 --trigger-http --timeout 540 --memory 1024 --entry-point=functionName
```

And calls to the functions are straightforward:

```
        let response = fetch(
            "https://us-central1-projectname.cloudfunctions.net/functionName",
            {
                method: "post",
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            }
        );
```

What's going on here? How can I force invocations to always use the latest version?

**UPDATE:**

After investigating this much more thoroughly, what I've uncovered is that the functions are actually running the latest version every time, but that they often (though not always) maintain state between calls when under high load. This is mentioned (although not that thoroughly) in the Cloud Functions documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#function_instance_lifespan).

This means that code contained in a module and loaded via require (e.g. `const db = require("../lib/myDatabaseService");`) may be run once and then persist, so console logs at the top of the module (outside of exported functions) were only appearing once. For example:

```
console.log("DB LIBRARY v2"); // Only appears on cold starts...
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const uri = `mongodb+srv://myConnectionUri`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {});

async function connectDB() { ... }
module.exports.connectDB = connectDB;

...
```

That said, having this code persist between function invocations isn't always desirable. For example, having my database connection persist was leading to a high number of disconnects in the middle of write operations during subsequent invocations.

Obviously this behavior saves resources, but in cases where you always want a new variable is it possible to selectively prevent this behavior?

Updating this question to: How to force cloud functions not to persist variables between invocations?

Comment: Are you sure that the function is healthy and well deployed? What's the size (in number of line for example) of the function that you deploy? I also already observe this behavior and there are several factors that can increase the risk to fall into this situation;

Comment: This is my speculative guess... Can it be that the cloud function is "in use" all the time? I mean that new versions - are instances after the "cold start". Thus, if a "cold start" happens - a new version of the cloud function is launched. Otherwise, the old version is used, until there is some pause in the invocation stream, and the memory for the cloud functino is reclaimed?

Comment: Could you try with some hello world tests? I mean, could you create a simple function that throws the hello world and then updating it to check if the string changes? (for example "hello world update 1"), For me it is working correctly but I think this tests will tell us if there is something wrong with that specific project

Comment: Edited the question based on further investigation. Thanks @al-dann for the guess, which lead me down this path!

Comment: I don't think is an answer, but I think that the solution would be to bring another approach to importing data. could you share with us why are you importing data at the same time that the libraries?